# Saving data from API for other modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a hard time retrieving data from a WEB API service in Angular 8.

I have a service which calls the API:

```
return this.http.get<UserSession>(uri)
  .pipe(map((json: UserSession) => this.EntryFormAdapter(json)));
```

This in turn calls a data adapter to convert the json, not sure if this is needed, but it is strongly typed. As a side note, the UserSession constructor does not work is I add properties to it.

UserSession (working):

```
export class UserSession {
  public SessionId: string;
  public SessionTimeout: number;
  public User: User;
}
```

UserSession (not working):

```
export class UserSession {
  constructor (public SessionId: string,
      public SessionTimeout: number,
      public User: User) { }
}
```

I need to store the UserSession in global data so the SessionId is accessible to my HMAC HttpInterceptor.

Interceptor (partial):

```
constructor(private userSession: Observable<UserSession>) {
    this.userSession.subscribe(us => this.sessionId = us.SessionId);
}
```

I have spent hours trying to figure these two issues out:
1) How to get a parameterized constructor to work
2) How to store a global UserSession object to use in other modules.

Comment: Subscription within an interceptor constructor doesn't look right. Where is your UserSession Object stored?

Comment: I actually removed that since I didn't know how to set anything on an Observable oject, like : var us = Observable<UserSession>; us.SessionId = 'abc';

I am now trying to set a global variable using this code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x32any?file=src%2Fapp%2Fglobals.ts

And it doesn't call my service any longer.

Comment: I suggest you get in touch with service pattern or store

Answer (score 0):

In app.module.ts, I had to add UserSession to the provider array:

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    AddIssueComponent
  ],
    imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
      { path: 'add-issue', component: AddIssueComponent },
    ])
    ],
    providers: [ApiService, UserSession, AppSettings, AppSettingsService,
        //{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: getSettings, deps: [AppSettingsService, ApiService, AppSettings], multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HmacInterceptorComponent, multi: true }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```